# How to open, delete columns and save a xls file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to know how to open a xls file that is already made, I want to delete some columns and then save the file. This is what I have but I get an error when I want to delete the columns. How do I use the DataFrame function to delete columns and then save.

**Read in excel file**

```
Workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Python/Python37/Files/firstCopy.xls", on_demand=True)
worksheet = Workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
```

**Delete a column**

```
df.DataFrame.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate', 'EmployeeID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
Workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Comment: `df.DataFrame.drop(...)` looks like malformed Pandas code that has nothing to do with the other 3 lines of code related to `xlrd`.  Are you trying to load the data into a Pandas DataFrame, modify it, and save it back to Excel?  Otherwise, you should leave Pandas out of it.

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas to delete columns. But from my understanding, pandas doesn't work with xls. I don't know how to delete columns with xlrd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('firstCopy.xls')

df.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate', 'EmployeeID'], axis=1)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't delete the 3 columns I need to remove. They still show up. Just so I understand, df.drop, completely drops the columns. I did change the file to a complete location ('C:/Python/Python37/Files/output.xlsx')

Comment: add   inplace=True after axis=1

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('firstCopy.xls')

df.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate', 'EmployeeID'], axis=1, inplace = True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

writer.save()
```